# JQuery select on <script></script> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have the following script used in html.twig page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/jquery-ui-1.11.2/external/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/js/jeoquery.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="my_prototype"> 
 <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                           // my first textarea
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                           // my second textarea     
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                           // my first input
                   <label for="my_date">Date</label>
                   <input type="text" id="my_date" name="my_datename" maxlength="10" class="form-control" />
            </div>    
</div>
</script>
```

My question is: How can I select "my_date" in jquery ? I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#my_date').datepicker();
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What does your `myFunction()` do?

Comment: @Justinas : it's the datepicker() function ! (jquery-ui)

Comment: Did you load jQuery and jQuery UI beforehand?

Comment: So why not calling `$("#my_date").datepicker()` instead of not existing `.myFunction()` ?

Comment: Why are your divs inside script tags? Did you load jquery library?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is pretty meaningless. Does it produce errors in the console? Have you wrapped the jQuery code in `$(function () { ... })` where applicable?

Comment: That was just an example, I've called  $("#my_date").datepicker() and I loaded jQuery and jQuery UI in my code.

Comment: Why is that HTML in script tags? You haven't explained that.

Comment: My divs are inside script tags because I use it as a prototype to generate an array of forms, When I put these divs inside a "div" tags, that works....

Comment: [The selector works btw](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/2bv7yke1/)

Comment: Plus 1 just because of the prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do the same with a jQuery object rather than a prototype?

e.g.: (I removed the id attributes so you can have more than one)

```
var $proto = $('<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        // my first textarea
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        // my second textarea     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       // my first input
       <label>Date</label>
       <input type="text" class="date_field" name="my_datename" maxlength="10" class="form-control" />
    </div>    
</div>");
```

This gives you a DOM structure you can insert where you need to.

Plus you can use

```
$proto.find('.date_field').datepicker();
```

...or you may have to insert it first and then call the datepicker extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've put these tags between script tags because you're using it as a template.
Applying jquery-ui datepicker works on actual dom elements.
So you need to first apply your template and generate the "real" elements, then apply the datepicker.

Edit: and watch what happens with the id, when you generate multiple forms, you shouldn't have the same id multiple times. If it's transformed in something like "my_date_1", "my_date_2", maybe you're better off using a dedicated class for identifying the datepicker inputs instead of the id.

Comment: Exactly, I'm using it as a template. What do you mean by " generate the "real" elements ", how can I do it ? Thanks

Comment: Meaning, apply your template, generate the array of forms and only after this apply .datepicker() on all of them.